# The questions related to Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner. I can't solve these two problems:

1:

> Error:(20, 20) error: cannot find symbol variable mQuestionBank

2:

> Error:(20, 20) error: cannot find symbol variable mQuestionBank

Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private android.widget.Button mTrueButton;
    private android.widget.Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question;
        question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();

        int messageResId = 0;

        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    private TrueFalse[] mQuesionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_1, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_2, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_3, false),
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

        mTrueButton = (android.widget.Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });

        mFalseButton = (android.widget.Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(android.view.View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });

        mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

        updateQuestion();

    }
}
```

I will be very grateful to those who will intelligibly and clearly explain!

Comment: You haven't defined `mQuestionBank` anywhere in your code

Comment: How it is correct to make it?

Comment: Where are you defining these questions? It looks like it's supposed to be an array of integers, but you never define it or give it any values. Even if you just add `private int[] mQuestionsBank = new int[???]` you'll still only get an array filled with zeros. What it is that you want? (note the '???' should be the size of the array)

Comment: are you a beginner in programming or beginner in Android?

Comment: question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion(); !!!! declaring question as int???? Seriously you are trying to show integer in mQuestionTextView? or you are trying to show a question??

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo in

```
private TrueFalse[] mQuesionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_1, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_2, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_3, false),
};
```

There is a **t** missing in mQuesionBank. it should be mQuestionBank.